# How to add the value to a specific row data in table(Parent) from child page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two pages First.html and Second.html. In Second.html i have one search button that redirect to second.html and once I choose the value it will populate the value in first.html. But the problem is in first.html the table has two id ="major". Based on the search button it will populate the value in the particular major box. How to achieve this ?

Comment: ID's are supposed to be globally unique. Assign classes instead.

Comment: Not clear about Second.html redirects to second.hmtl... Can you elaborate on that (Please change the text of the question). Also note that in English and most other languages in the world, the punctuation comes after the last letter in the sentence not before the first letter in a sentence

Comment: Just go with the parent id or parent class so it will make difference. Like In above code take form id "Basicinfo" as parent id and use it like that  
$(#Basicinfo #major);

Answer (score 0):

You can access two different elements with same id like this:

```
var table=$("table#major");
var inputelement=$("input#major");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested, IDs should be unique in your HTML. To determine which row you want to manipulate, use the ID from the table and use the table's rows collection...

```
document.getElementById("Major").rows[rowNumber].cells[1].children[0].value;
```

...rowNumber will probably need to be manipulated to ensure you are on the correct row.  With your code, the first row you care about is row 2.